# Sphere projection option is missing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to map a texture to a sphere without UV mapping, and here's my node setup:
[image: all info needed]

I wanted to set the image texture projection to "sphere", as I saw it being used in a tutorial, but as the picture shows, I don't have the option to use sphere projections. I am using Cycles render and have the texture on a UV sphere, not an icosphere.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? Seems like an outdated version

Comment: upgrade to a newer version of blender.

Comment: My blender version: Blender 2.71. Newest version:  2.77a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the screenshots shown Blender version 2.71 was installed. One should have upgraded Blender to a newer version as this functionality was added [as of 2.74](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/Cycles):

> **Nodes**
>    Image texture node now supports sphere and tube mapping.
>   [12ccac6](https://developer.blender.org/rB12ccac6), [dda3554](https://developer.blender.org/rBdda3554)

Thank you cegaton